# I want to read a csv file to omron plc

Tags: file, csv, plc

I want to read a csv file to omron plc. It will be with usb.  I have hmi panel NB 5Q-TWOO1B and plc OMRON CP1L-E. If you have about that problem You can example code send me. it's enough for me.

Comment: What is your problem? Access file or analyze its content? You do not know how to read file or how to extract content from it.

Comment: yes. I want to read the CSV file accessed from usb. it's possible I know but it's can only one column. I need example a code for more column.

Comment: it can only one column what? Column or row? Show code that you already have.

Comment: its number rows not important. Column number of csv file is important for me. I dont have code now. I am writing ST language or with ladder.

Answer (score 0):

Enter: http://"IP address of HMI"/usbdisk.html in a web browser to access it.

https://www.myomron.com/index.php?action=kb&article=1660